# How to change a column mode in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an `INTEGER` type column in bigquery table, which is set to `NULLABLE` as in mode. Is there any way to change the field mode from `NULLABLE` to `0` in bigquery using API, bq console or UI?

I have read the docs and its clearly showing we can change the mode from `REQUIRED` to `NULLABLE`. But there is no hint on changing it from `NULLABLE` to `0`. I have data already exists in the table which I don't want to lose.

Please help if there is any way I can do that.

Comment: I thought the field mode could only be "NULLABLE, REQUIRED or REPEATED". Is there  documentation telling it could be "0"?

Comment: I don't know @YunZhang I need that to be 0 value by default. I guess it should be updated in the mode(if it is supported).

Comment: I think this is not supported as described here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623395/default-values-for-columns-in-big-query-tables#:~:text=A%20nullable%20column%20can%20(trivially,will%20have%20the%20NULL%20value)).

Comment: Default column value is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a default value is not supported, however this can be easily achieved in a query using `IFNULL`

For example

```
SELECT IFNULL(a, 0) AS field
FROM (
  SELECT 2 AS a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS a
)
```

If you are loading data from external source, you could create a staging table and then run a query to generate the data for your main table using `IFNULL`, would need more details to give a more specific answer.

Comment: No @QueryStash actually i was looking for a default column value (0 for instance) in bigquery table. Not a partial solution.

Comment: As mentioned the default value is not possible in BigQuery, so only alternate solutions available.

Answer (score 1):

What might resolve your situation - is to make use of BigQuery `default value` column property with a custom `default value expression` for a specific column.

BigQuery allows to configure **Mode, Name, Type**
and [Default Value](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values#default_value_expression) column properties. Where `default value` can be either one of defaults such as [CURRENT_TIME, RAND, ...](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values#default_value_expression) expressions or a custom one, based on the logic defined by you.

Assume, you create table with following schema:

```
[    
{
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "A",
  "type": "STRING",
  "default_value_expression": CURRENT_DATE
},
{
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "B",
  "type": "INTEGER",
  "default_value_expression": 0
}
]
```

- Column `A` utilizes `default value` as `CURRENT_DATE()`, which is built in one
- Column `B` utilizes `default value` as `0`, which is defined by ourselves

Pay attention, in general, to make use of `default value` feature, column `mode` has to be `NULLABLE`, meaning `default value` will be "triggered" when `NULL` value will be ingested.

Please find detailed explanation in official [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values#console)