# Setup Big Query table with UUID column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, uuid

Between the "[BigQuery default column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623395/default-values-for-columns-in-big-query-tables)" and "[Create UUID columns in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49404747/create-a-column-of-uuids-in-google-bigquery)" posts, it looks like BQ recently started supporting the concept of a UUID, but is there a pattern for generating UUID (similar to a postgres/SQL trigger) values for each record upon insertion into the BQ table?

As an aside, I'm not seeing a way to automatically generate timestamp values for `created_date_time` and `modified_date_time` (typically another trigger) fields-- should I just focus on generating these values (UUIDs and timestamps) in the logic making the insertion request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery supports neither default values nor triggers.  So, you have to assign these values explicitly when rows are inserted:

```
create table `test` (
    id string,
    x int64,
    created_at timestamp
);

INSERT INTO `test` (id, x, created_at)
    values (generate_uuid(), 1, current_timestamp);
```

I imagine that Google will add default values in the not-to-distant future.